# Excel VBA: Worksheet_change doesn't detect recalculation

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA function which works fine for manual cell change, but it does'nt work for column where the =AVERAGE() function is. What I'm trying to do is to change font color, where average is. If average is greater than 0.6 then font colorIndex is 3 and if average column value is less or equal to 0.6 set font colorIndex to 10.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range(Target.Dependents.Address)
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(c, Range("X:AI")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("H" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("G" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("H" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("G" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If

...

        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AX:AX")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > 0.6 Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= 0.6 Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` isn't triggered by cell changes due to formulas: you need to use `Worksheet_Calculate` for that.

Comment: I have read somewhere that you can't get cell location like in Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) and I need it ;/

Comment: No - there is no `Target` equivalent in the Calculate event: you are stuck having to monitor the whole range of interest

Comment: Using the dependents member of the range object should be valid. This approach looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Heres working code that I have found working for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(c, Range("X:AI")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("H" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("G" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("H" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("G" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
            Range("AK" & c.Row).Value = "=AVERAGE(X" & c.Row & ":AI" & c.Row & ")"

        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AL:AM")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("K" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("J" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("K" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("J" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AN:AP")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("N" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("M" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("N" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("M" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
            Range("AQ" & c.Row).Value = "=AVERAGE(AN" & c.Row & ":AP" & c.Row & ")"

        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AR:AT")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("Q" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("P" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("Q" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("P" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
            Range("AU" & c.Row).Value = "=AVERAGE(AR" & c.Row & ":AT" & c.Row & ")"
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AV:AX")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("T" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("S" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("T" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("S" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
            Range("AY" & c.Row).Value = "=AVERAGE(AV" & c.Row & ":AX" & c.Row & ")"
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("BE:BG")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("T" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("S" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("T" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("S" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AK:AK")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("H" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("G" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("H" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("G" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AU:AU")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("Q" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("P" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("Q" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("P" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AY:AY")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("T" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("S" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("T" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("S" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

This line manualy updates average cell and then Worksheet_Change does the job.

```
Range("AK" & c.Row).Value = "=AVERAGE(X" & c.Row & ":AI" & c.Row & ")"
```